# $n$th power residue conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cubic-reciprocity

Let $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)_n$ be the $n$th power residue symbol such that when $a$ is an $n$th power residue $\pmod p$, $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)_n=1$ otherwise $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)_n=\zeta$. Let $f_n(x)$ be a defining polynomial for the $n$th cyclotomic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/n})$. Suppose that there exists some integer $m$ such that $f_n(m)=0 \pmod {n^2}$, and there are primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p=f_n(z)$ and $q=f_n(z+a)$. Then $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)_n = \left(\dfrac{a}{q}\right)_n$. When $n=3$, this conjecture agrees with [cubic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity) theorems. The same is true for $n=4$.

Here is an example of the conjecture for $n=5$:

$f_5(x)=x^4+5x^3+10x^2+25$ and $f_5(0)=0\pmod {5^2}$

$a=3$, $p=f_5(1)=41$ and $q=f_5(1+a)=f_5(4)=761$ are both prime, thus

$\left(\dfrac{3}{41}\right)_5 = \left(\dfrac{3}{761}\right)_5$.

Since $3$ is a quintic residue $\pmod {41}$, then it is also a quintic residue of $761$. In general, if $p=f_5(3a+1)$ is prime, then $3$ is a quintic residue $\pmod p$.

Comment: Your $n$-th power residue symbol is *not* standard when $n > 2$: its value at numbers that are not $n$th powers mod $p$ should *not* be $-1$, but some $n$th root of unity if you want the symbol to be multiplicative in any reasonable way.  Also, using ordinary prime numbers rather than prime ideals in $\mathbf Z[e^{2\pi i/n}]$ seems unusual, e.g., cubic reciprocity is usually expressed in terms of $\mathbf Z[e^{2\pi i/3}]$ and quartic (biquadratic) reciprocity is usually expressed in terms of $\mathbf Z[e^{2\pi i/4}] = \mathbf Z[i]$. Your conjecture has a gap: what type of number is $z$?

Comment: @KCd changing -1 to a root of unity is only nessesary when dealing with cosets of the groups of $n$th power residues but I changed it anyways. As for $z$, like $x, a,$ and $n$ is an integer.

Comment: For $n > 2$, an $n$th power residue symbol does not just have two nonzero values, "1 and $\zeta$".  Its nonzero values run over *all* $n$th roots of unity, in order to be multiplicative in $a$, so your description of $(\frac{a}{p})_n$ is unusual (esp. since $p$ need not be prime in $\mathbf Z[e^{2\pi i/n}]$, e.g., $p = 41$ when $n = 5$.  Where are you getting your description of power residue symbols from?

Comment: @KCd In theory, yes your assertion is correct, but here we only care about the solvability of $a=x^n \pmod p$, and there is only two "values". Solvable $(1)$ or non-solvable $(-1)$ or a particular root of unity.